# How to sum up the columns based on a particular column project name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a report basically and I have this following structure

**TABLE 1:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Projects Worked</th>
    <th>Hours Done</th>
    <th>SPAM</th>
    <th>Under Review</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Project A</td>
    <td>3.5</td>
    <td>0.5</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Project B</td>
    <td>6.5</td>
    <td>5.2</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Project A</td>
    <td>8.2</td>
    <td>2.5</td>
    <td>6.3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Project C</td>
    <td>2.5</td>
    <td>5.6</td>
    <td>2.69</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Project B</td>
    <td>2.5</td>
    <td>5.21</td>
    <td>2.90</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

**What I want is**

**TABLE 2:**

Total of the Projects in a single line if projects are same. For example see this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Projects Worked</th>
    <th>Hours Done</th>
    <th>SPAM</th>
    <th>Under Review</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Project A</td>
    <td>11.7</td>
    <td>3.0</td>
    <td>6.3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Project B</td>
    <td>6.5</td>
    <td>5.2</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Project C</td>
    <td>9.0</td>
    <td>10.41</td>
    <td>3.90</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

If you see, In Table 2, we have summation of Project A in one line, summation of Project B in next line and then Project C.

I tried using aggregate function but it returns nothing.

**Please note:** This the numbers in decimals **are actually nvarchars**.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want aggregation:

```
select
    project_worked,
    sum(cast(hours_done as decimal(10, 3))) hours_done,
    sum(cast(spam as decimal(10, 3))) spam,
    sum(cast(under_review as decimal(10, 3))) under_review
from mytable
group by project_worked
order by project_worked
```

I added a step for casting the strings to numbers; whether this will work properly or generate errors depends on how well formated your data is. You should really fix your model to store numbers as numbers.

Comment: I tried your solution, it is saying "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."

Comment: @n00b_programmer: probably, you have formatting issues in your string column (I mentioned that in my answer)... You can try this query to show the offending values in a given column: `select hours_done from mytable where try_cast(hours_done as decimal(10, 3)) is null`.